# Changing EXIF data of a TIF file affects the rest metadata

Tags: python, metadata, tiff, exif, piexif

I am using `piexif` library to modify the gps altitude of a tif file's EXIF data. This is my implementation:

```
import piexif
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 1000000000

fname_1='initial.tif'
fname_2='new_file.tif'
img = Image.open(fname_1)
exif_dict = piexif.load(fname_1)
new_exif_dict = exif_dict
new_exif_dict['GPS'][piexif.GPSIFD.GPSAltitude] = (140, 1)
del new_exif_dict['0th'][50714]  # I delete this because it causes an error for class type for some reason. It happens even if I dump the original metadata as they are, to a new tif file

exif_bytes = piexif.dump(new_exif_dict)
im = Image.open(fname_1)
im.save(fname_2, exif=exif_bytes)
```

The code works, however the metadata are now a lot less on the new tif photo than the original one. Even the GPS coordinates are lost.

My question is how could I change the tif file's metadata about GPS without affecting the rest?

Comment: Would it work if you started with `new_exif_dict` being a full copy of `exif_dict` where you only change the fields you want to modify, instead of creating your `new_exif_dict` by explicitly listing the field you currently initialize it with?

Comment: Just tried it but many of the metadata are still lost. However, I just updated the code with your suggestion as it's much simpler. I was fooled from documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PIL and saving the image will recompress the data and rewrite or remove many tags.  You can use a different library that alters less.  For instance, if you are only working with tiff files, you can do this with the `tifftools` python package via the command line:

```
tifftools set --set GPSAltitude,0,GPSIFD:0 140,1 IMG_0036_1.tif new_file.tif
```

or via python:

```
import tifftools

# Load all tag information from the file
info = tifftools.read_tiff('IMG_0036_1.tif')
# Get a reference to the IFD with GPS tags.  If the GPS data is in a different
# location, you might need to change this.
gpsifd = info['ifds'][0]['tags'][tifftools.Tag.GPSIFD.value]['ifds'][0][0]
# Set the altitude tag; this assumes it already exists and is stored as a rational
gpsifd['tags'][tifftools.constants.GPSTag.GPSAltitude.value]['data'] = [140, 1]
# Write the output; this copies all image data from the original file.
tifftools.write_tiff(info, 'new_file.tif')
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of tifftools.

Comment: Works like a charm! And I don't notice any metadata loss either. Thank you!

Comment: May I ask, how could I update the same tif file's data? Above code doesn't seem to work with the same tif file.

Comment: I've just noticed the allowExisting=True on write_tif but for some reason it results in never-ending execution for some reason

Comment: `tifftools always writes the entire file, so it has to write to a different file that the source. 
 The `allowExisting` flag let's it overwrite an existing output file (but not the same as the input).  The higher level commands write to a new temporary file and then replace the original file with that.  The `tifftools.commands.tiff_set` function, for instance, is the equivalent of the `tiff set ...` command line and will handle this.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying it is not possible to update a file's existing exif data, right?

Comment: Right.  The `tiff_set` function writes a temp file and replaces the original file with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) to modify the file in-place:

```
import tifffile

# open the TIFF file for reading and writing
with tifffile.TiffFile(filename, mode='r+b') as tif:
    # get the GPS tag of the first IFD/page
    gpstag = tif.pages[0].tags['GPSTag']
    # seek to the beginning of the GPSIFD
    tif.filehandle.seek(gpstag.valueoffset)
    # load the IFD
    gpsifd = tifffile.TiffPage(tif, None)
    # patch the GPSAltitude (6) field
    gpsifd.tags[6].overwrite(tif, (140, 1))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The error is TypeError: unexpected keyword argument: mode Seems like there is no "mode" parameter. Could you please modify your answer?

Comment: You are likely using an outdated version of tifffile. There is a [mode parameter](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/v2021.3.31/tifffile/tifffile.py#L2835)

Comment: You are right. `pip install` got me an older version because I used Python 3.6. It seems like from  v2020.10.1 Tifffile requires python >= 3.7

Comment: Do you know how could I update the existing file using python2.7?